# Need Clarification on vim leader key

Tags: vim, neovim

//mapping1

```
tnoremap <Esc> <C-\\> <C-n>
```

// mapping2

```
let localleader = "\\"

tnoremap <Esc> C<localleader> <C-n>
```

I tried to modify the above mapping by replacing '\' by a localleader;

But it just prints C\ ^N in the terminal. Can anyone help me to find the mistake?

Comment: See `:help localleader` for a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to VIM's documentation accessed by the command `:help localleader`, you should assign the "\\" to a `maplocalleader` variable, such as:

```
let maplocalleader = "\\"

tnoremap <Esc> C<LocalLeader> <C-n>
```